# input box formula

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code, I want to see the sum formula so that I can see which cells are adding, but code is reflection only result not formula 
`[like this" =SUM(B2:F2)].`
Hope you understand my issue and help on this.

```
Sub Macro6()
Dim UserResponse As Range
Dim Result As Range
Set Result = Application.InputBox("Select cell where you want result", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set UserResponse = Application.InputBox("select a range with the mouse", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Result.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(UserResponse)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get downvoted for this answer but it will be worth it!

`MsgBox "=SUM(" & Replace(UserResponse.Address, Chr(36), vbNullString) & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. That should work.

```
Sub Macro6()
Dim UserResponse As Range
Dim Result As Range

Set Result = Application.InputBox("Select cell where you want result", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Set UserResponse = Application.InputBox("select a range with the mouse", Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
Result.Formula = "=SUM(" & UserResponse.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

Or in the last line you can use `"=SUM(" & UserResponse.Address (False, False) & ")"` so the formula is not in absolute reference.